# Try - catch SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I cant force my error sad face to come up on this code. Can someone help please I just get a normal error message not the one in the catch. I just take out a bit of code to force an error is this right

```
declare @Color Table
(color char(12))

insert @Color 
Values('white'),
('Red'),
('black'),
('yellow');

Declare @make Table 
(make char(12))

insert @make
Values('Polo'),
('Golf'),
('A1'),
('Metro');

Begin try   
Select *
  From @Color Cross Join @make ;   
End Try    
Begin Catch
   PRINT ';('   
end catch
  Print 'Done'
```

Comment: Why do you expect your select query to fail? It is perfectly valid in the sample you've provided. So since it will not fail - catch block will never be executed.

Comment: `Select * From @Color Cross Join @make ;` is normal correct query.

Comment: It's not that I want it to fail I'm trying to make it fail to test the catch works but if I take out a bit of code I get the normal error message.  I want to know why it's not catching even if there is an error?

Comment: @NickRichards if you want to rise an `Exception` write following . `THROW;`

Comment: Tag dbms product used. (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: Assuming this is not real code, you're using SQL Server, and you're just testing out using TRY/CATCH to learn it - you can force an error to be thrown with [RAISERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

Comment: I'm I understanding this wrong? If I for example remove the (F) from 'From'  I get the error message I always get. If there is an error why doesn't it go it 'Catch and I get ':(' .' why do I get the system error still?

Comment: You misunderstand - TRY/CATCH won't catch errors in the SQL you have written, but the errors in the execution when it runs - the same as (nearly) every other programming language behaves. You won't even get to run the query if the syntax is invalid (except in some cases with dynamic SQL).

Comment: Compilation errors and runtime errors are two completely different things.  You're getting that error because your syntax is wrong and it doesn't even know what you're trying to do.  If you want to hit a `CATCH` block, your code needs to compile.  To test it, you should add a `RAISERROR` inside your `TRY`.

Comment: Please could you give me some code to copy I'm quite knew to this only if you have time?

Comment: @NickRichards why don't you check the documentation? SO isn't a discussion site, in fact requests for tutorials are explicitly out of scope. You can't learn about a concept by looking a someone else's code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I ran your excerpt in SQL Server 2012, and it did not produce an error at all. I got a result set of 16 rows.

Here is some code that will catch an error and tell you what went wrong:

```
DECLARE @Color TABLE
(color char(12));

INSERT @Color 
VALUES('white'),
('Red'),
('black'),
('yellow');

BEGIN TRY;
    SELECT CAST(color AS int)
        FROM @Color;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH;
```

The output is:

[image: Output of error handler]

Comment: Thank you I see now this failed because it cant make the Color into a number but the code was written okay so it's a run time error. I see. Thank you very much :)